# Overriding return type in child class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

Given is the class `IPrinterManager` and its child class `ColorPrinterManager`. `ColorPrinter` is a child class of `AbstractPrinter`. Compilation aborts with the message `ColorPrinterManager::print is not a covariant of IPrinterManager::print`. How can I fix this issue?

```
class IPrinterManager
{
public:

   virtual std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractPrinter>>* print(std::string text) = 0;

};

class ColorPrinterManager : public IPrinterManager
{
public:

   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ColorPrinter>>* print(std::string text);

};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to return `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractPrinter>>*`. There is no going around it. You can still populate it by `ColorPrinter` pointers.

Covariant return types allow you to specify a more derived type, as the return type of a virtual function. But `vector`s of pointers have no such relationships.

---

Also, consider returning by value. With NRVO and move semantics, vectors are really good at efficiently managing their resources.

Comment: But I want to enforce that just color printers can be returned. Is there no other way to do that?

Comment: @user1056903, your implementation is how you enforce that, clients shouldn't have to care. If you want to do this because `AbstractPrinter` doesn't provide an adequate interface to work with, you need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

`ColorPrinter` might be derived from `AbstractPrinter` but `shared_ptr<ColorPrinter>`  is not derived from `shared_ptr<AbstractPrinter>`  and `vector<shared_ptr<ColorPrinter>>`  is not derived from `vector<shared_ptr<AbstractPrinter>>`. So your `print` functions are not covariants.

You need to stick with `vector<shared_ptr<AbstractPrinter>>`. Of course if you have code like

```
ColorPrinterManager pm;
auto v = pm.print(string("bla"));
for(auto &s : v) {
    // This gives you the AbstractPrinter
    auto p = s.get();
    // If you called ColorPrinterManager you know that all printers are ColorPrinter
    auto p2 = dynamic_cast<ColorPrinter*>(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need covariant return types here, one method is to define a parallel hierarchy of printer containers alongside that of printers, and use it instead of `std::vector`.

```
// printers
class AbstractPrinter { ...

class ColourPrinter : public AbstractPrinter { ...

// printer collections
class AbstractPrinterCollection {
      public: virtual AbstractPrinter* get(int i) = 0; ...

class ColourPrinterCollection : public AbstractPrinterCollection {
      public: ColourPrinter* get(int i) override { ... }
      private: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ColourPrinter>> vec; ...
```

Note 1: `get` returns a regular pointer, not a shared pointer. This is because we need it to have covariant return types, and it doesn't work with smart pointers. (There are ways around it).

Note 2: only leaf classes in the entire hierarchy have data members (like an actual container with actual printers), the base class and the intermediate classes delegate data to the leaves, and may be fully abstract.

Note 3: there's no `put` in the AbstractPrinterCollection (there may be `put` in leaf classes).

Note 4: this is rather cumbersome. Consider making `print` *non-virtual* (and return by value).